# How to convert serde_json::Value into concrete type implementing Deserialize trait?

Tags: json, rust

I am writing a websocket server which deserializes incoming frames into a `serde_json::Value` and then passes this value to (potentially many) callbacks. I would like the callbacks to convert the `serde_json::Value` to a new type (e.g. `MyType` in the example below) without an encode/decode pass. It seems to me that the serde machinery should have enough information to do this (with the possibility of an error if the contained fields and types do not match). In the example below, the function `to_my_type()` stands in for this callback function. Is is the encode/decode that I want to bypass from this function.

I could of course pass the raw encoded data to each callback, but then each callback will have to do the decoding separately. I want to keep the function signature of the callbacks taking an argument of type `serde_json::Value` so that different callbacks can get different types but that I can register them all with a common function signature.

```
#![feature(proc_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyType {
    a: bool,
}

fn as_json(a: &MyType) -> serde_json::Value {
    let buf = serde_json::to_vec(a).unwrap();
    serde_json::from_slice::<serde_json::Value>(&buf).unwrap()
}

fn to_my_type(value: serde_json::Value) -> MyType {
    // How to convert a serde_json::Value into MyType without encode/decode pass?
    let buf = serde_json::to_vec(&value).unwrap();
    serde_json::from_slice::<MyType>(&buf).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let store = MyType{a: true};
    let raw_json = as_json(&store);
    let _store2 = to_my_type(raw_json);
}
```

Comment: can you make your question more explicit? I think it's somehow implicit in the paragraphs (something like "how to register those conversion functions in serde"), and maybe state what you already tried..?

Comment: The question is the title of my post "How to convert serde_json::Value into concrete type implementing Deserialize trait?" and again repeated in the example code "How to convert a serde_json::Value into MyType without encode/decode pass?"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [`serde_json::from_value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/fn.from_value.html) function to convert a `Value` to any type that implements `Deserialize`:

```
fn to_my_type(value: serde_json::Value) -> MyType {
    serde_json::from_value(value).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Note that `serde_json::Value` is itself a `serde::Deserializer`, so you can also just do `<MyType as Deserialize>::deserialize(value)` (which is in fact how `serde_json::from_value` is implemented). This fact is useful when dealing with something that wants a generic deserializer.